# Почему может подгружаться не вся статика?

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

У меня django проект стоит на vps, пару дней назад все отлично работало, я перезапустил gunicorn, чтобы у меня обновились формы. Все было хорошо, но посмотрев через день, у меня стала подгружаться не вся статика
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все файлы лежат в директории, collectstatic делал.
При запуске gunicorn`а не выводило что он не находит статику.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В чем может быть причина этого? Статика у меня подгружается через django, а не через nginx.

Comment: а что в настройках django? откуда он берет статику? P.S. вроде бы по дефолту он не берет файлы из из collectstatic..

Comment: В настройках все вроде корректно, тк до этого долгое время все отлично работало, и никакие настройки не менялись

Comment: приведите текст настроек а именно STATIC_*** и MEDIA_***

Comment: STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)

Comment: Рискну предположить что статика отдается из папки static а collectstatic больше для красоты. Попробуйте запихнуть туда разные файлы и посмотрите что будет видеть сайт.

Comment: В assets и static?

Comment: в static и assets, collectstatic если есть, подозреваю что изменение в первой будут видны на сайте а во второй нет. P.S, Так будет видно откуда вы выводите файлы

Comment: Изменил файл в static, на сайте ничего не изменилось, прописал collectstatic, в assets этот файл обновился, но на сайте опять же нет изменений

Comment: Посмотрел с телефона, вообще статика не подгружается

Comment: Да, статика вообще не подгружается. Зашел через другой браузер

Comment: если не отдает вообще то что у вас стоит в DEBUG в settings.py?

Comment: стоит DEBUG = False

Comment: DEBUG False django перестанет отдавать статику (для этого и ставится nginx), а DEBUG True будет отдавать отладочную инфу всем в общем тоже плохо.

Comment: Как у меня тогда работало, если DEBUG = False уже давно, хмм

Comment: Если через nginx раздавать, то в html файле по другому подключаться будет, или так же?

Comment: Все также. постораюсь описать виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Причина в `DEBUG = False` с отключенной отладкой Django не обрабатывает статические файлы для этого можно использовать например nginx.
Примерная настройка под linux:

### Установка

```bsh
apt install python3
apt install python3-pip
apt install nginx
apt install nano
pip3 install django
pip3 install gunicorn
```

#### Создаем наш проект

```bsh
django-admin.py startproject myproject
```

не забываем про collectstatic перед выкладкой, чтобы nginx мог ее корректно подгружать.

```bsh
python3 manage.py collectstatic
```

Проект лучше создавать в виртуальном окружении.

#### Проверяем gunicorn

Из папки проекта там где лежит manage.py запускаем gunicorn указав Ваш IP

```bsh
gunicorn myproject.wsgi:application --bind 111.111.111.111:8000
```

При этом сайт будет отображаться без статических файлов это нормально!

Иногда gunicorn может оставаться в памяти

```bsh
killall gunicorn
```

#### Создадим конфиг файл для gunicorn

```bsh
cd /opt/my_site/myproject/myproject` # каталог с settings.py
touch gunicorn.conf.py
```

Открываем

```bsh
nano gunicorn.conf.py
```

Пишем

```
bind = '127.0.0.1:8000'
workers = 3
user = "nobody"
```

### Настроим nginx

Перейдем в /etc/nginx/sites-available/

```bsh
cd /etc/nginx/sites-available/
```

и откроем default

```bsh
nano default
```

Удаляем оттуда все и пишем

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 111.111.111.111; # ip или доменное имя
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/site.log;

    location /static/ {
        root /opt/my_site/myproject/;  # где manage.py
        expires 30d;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
  }
```

Сохраняем, выходим, перезапускам nginx

```bsh
service nginx restart
```

Если все правильно переходим в браузере по адресу сайта и радуемся итогу.

### Автозапуск - systemd

Создадим и отредактируем файл настроек systemd
создадим конфиг и отредактируем его

```bsh
cd /etc/systemd/system/
touch myproject.service
nano myproject.conf
```

Содержимое файла:

```
[Unit]
Description=My_Project
After=nginx.service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/opt/my_site/env/bin/gunicorn myproject.wsgi:application -c /opt/my_site/myproject/myproject/gunicorn.conf.py
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Проверяем статус и подключаем его и запускаем:

```bsh
systemctl status myproject
systemctl enable myproject
systemctl start myproject
```

P.S. Обратите внимание что в nginx у меня папка статики = static (location /static/) У вас как понимаю будет папка assets. И настроена работа по http

Comment: Что-то у меня ничего не выходит, прописал расположение static в nginx(static потому что в конечном итоге в html так: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css">`), все равно ничего

Comment: `location /static/ { root /home/vexit/code/mysite; }`

Comment: а порт сервер все указано? попробуйте открыть например yoursite.name/static/css/style.css откроется?